# Сохранение добавленного текста после перезагрузки страницы (подобие добавления комментария) хотелось бы через localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

```html
<title>Пример</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>

<style>
  textarea {
    background: yellow;
  }
</style>

<h3>Ваше Имя: </h3>
<input type='text' id='exText' value='' />
<br>
<h3>Текст сообщения:</h3>
<textarea rows="6" cols="40" name="text" id='exText1' value='Текст'></textarea>
<input type='button' onclick='insertText();' value=' Отправить ' />
<div id='testDiv' style='width:98%; padding:5px; border:1px solid black; background-color:lightyellow;'>Комментарии:</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  function insertText() {
    testDiv = document.getElementById('testDiv');
    testDiv.innerHTML = testDiv.innerHTML + '<br><br>' + '<font color=blue  size=-1>Имя:</font>' + '<i>' + document.getElementById('exText').value + '</i>' + '<br>' + document.getElementById('exText1').value;
  }
  document.getElementById('exText').onkeydown = function(key) {
      if (key.keyCode == 13) {
        insertText();
      }
    }
    -- >
</script>
```

При вводе имени и любого текста нажать отправить снизу появится введенный текст, поменял текст, нажал отправить еще один появился, и мне нужно чтобы этот текст после перезагрузки страницы не удалялся.

Как это осуществить?

Comment: И что?​​​​​​​​​

Comment: вот при таком коде хочу чтобы при добавлении текста например пару строчек чтобы после перезагрузки они оставались

Comment: Ну а где у вас использование localStorage ?

Comment: так я прошу мне помочь осуществить сохранение этих строк после добавления через localStorage